# React - update or re-render parent component when navigating to another child

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have two components `ChildA` and `ChildB` which share a fair amount of UI elements plus the same logic to retrieve data from API before the component is rendered. The common logic and UI elements are externalized in `Parent` component.
The API call is executed from `Parent` in `useEffect` hook.
The common UI elements are rendered based on the data retrieved by the API call.

**Problem:**

When I navigate from `/parent/a` to `/parent/b`, the API call is not executed so the component doesn't update.

I guess the reason is `Parent` has already been mounted the first time I entered `{base_url}/parent/a` in the browser, so it doesn't execute `useEffect` a second time when I try to navigate to `/parent/b`. However I have no idea how to solve it. Am I going all wrong here?

**Steps to reproduce:**

- Enter URL `{base_url}/parent/a` in the browser ; the API call is executed, everything works fine
- Click a link to navigate to `/parent/b` ; the component doesn't update.

**Requirements:**

- I would like to avoid using class components as much as possible
- I don't use redux and I don't want to use it just to solve this problem

Routing:

```
<Route path="/parent/a" render={props => <Parent child={ChildA} name="child-a" {...props} /> } exact />
<Route path="/parent/b" render={props => <Parent child={ChildB} name="child-b" {...props} /> } exact />
```

Child A :

```
export default function ChildA() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Child A</h1>
            {/*Clicking this link will reproduce the issue*/}
            <Link to="b">Go to Child B</Link>
        </div>
    )    
}
```

Child B :

```
export default function ChildB() {    
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Child B</h1>
            {/*Clicking this link will reproduce the issue*/}
            <Link to="a">Go to Child A</Link>
        </div>
    )    
}
```

Parent :

```
interface ParentProps {
    child: any,
    name: string
}

export default function Parent(props: ParentProps) {    
    const Child = props.child

    const [model, setModel] = useState<Model | null>(null)


    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])


    function fetchData() {
        console.log('EXECUTING API CALL FOR:', props.name)
        // ...API call ommitted for brevity...
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Parent</h1>               
            {/* ...Display lots of UI depending on Model - omitted for brevity... */}
            <Child/>
        </div>
    )    
}
```

Comment: Are you using react-router-dom to handle navigation?

Comment: add `props.child` to `useEffect` dependency array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're passing an empty dependencies array, the effect only gets run once. You can add `props.name` to the dependencies array to make sure `fetchData` gets called when `props.name` changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  function fetchData() {
    console.log('Executing API call for:', props.name)
    // Fetch data
  }

  fetchData()
}, [props.name])
```

The `fetchData` function is added inside the effect to make the effect's dependencies clearly visible. I would recommend reading [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies) for more information. And you can use the `exhaustive-deps` ESLint rule which is a part of the [`eslint-plugin-react-hooks`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) package to help you find effects where the dependencies array does not include all the effect's dependencies.

Comment: I need to read more about the dependencies array. Thank you!